# Fatal error: Class 'Mosquitto\Client' not found

Tags: php, mqtt

I have been trying to publish a subscribe message using MQTT, but whenever I run my script it gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Mosquitto\Client' not found in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Mosquitto-PHP-master/examples/pub.php on line 3

This is connection:

```
$client->connect("localhost", 1883, 5);
```

I have downloaded code from below:
https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP

I tried to download code using pecl command but it gives me error:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/Mosquitto" install failed

The broker is working fine after firing the command. I got a message in new subscriber terminal - broker is working.

Can anyone let me know what mistake I made?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, and thanks for correction.Can you guys have any idea to resolve it?

Comment: sunil you did not include probably mostquitto client that is why

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But it works when i fire command from terminal :- 
mosquitto_pub -t topic/state -m "Hello world"; // Publisher
mosquitto_sub -t topic/state // subscriber....
But when i tried PHP script it did not work....

Comment: Just because you have the mosquitto command line client installed doesn't mean you have the MQTT PHP library installed.

Comment: Ok thanks, but i am using this one for php :- https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP.

Comment: Hi All, I have the exact issue any suggestion is appreciated

`PHP 5.6.40 (cli) (built: Apr 23 2019 11:14:34) 
Zend Engine v2.6.0, with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev`

Answer (score 0):

Installing mosquitto is different than installing a php extension.

This is issue shoes up when mosquitto module is not loaded properly

Use the below method to install mosquitto extension ( [Mosquitto-PHP](https://github.com/mgdm/Mosquitto-PHP) )

`phpize`

`./configure --with-mosquitto=/path/to/libmosquitto`

`make`

`make install`

for loading module add "extension=mosquitto.so" in php.ini file
To check loaded modules use phpinfo()

Find loaded .ini file with
`php -i | grep 'php.ini'`

The result will look like
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6

Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/etc/php/5.6/php.ini

for enabling module use "sudo php5enmod mosquitto"